# Online sites for real time bond prices

Tags: united-states, bonds

In this chart for bonds traded on [NYSE](http://www.nyse.com/bonds/nysebonds/Bonds_Symbol.html?val=A)

it seems a lot of bonds do not have a value for the 'Previous Close'. Considering that bonds trade in the open market like stocks, is there an online resource that shows OHLC, Last bid, Last Ask etc. i.e.a yahoo finance page for bonds. What are the websites real time bond trading prices  (just like level 2 real time stock quotes)? Because the above chart does not even AAPL bond data.

EDIT: I am asking specifically for US corporate bonds

Answer (score 1):

Bonds are extremely illiquid and have traditionally traded in bulk.  This has changed in recent years, but bonds used to be traded all by humans not too long ago.

Currently, price data is all proprietary.  Prices are reported to the usual data terminals such as Bloomberg, Reuters, etc, but brokers may also have price gathering tools and of course their own internal trade history.

Bonds are so illiquid that comparable bonds are usually referenced for a bond's price history.  This can be done because non-junk bonds are typically well-rated and consistent across ratings.

Answer (score 0):

FINRA lets you view recent trades, but as stated in the other answer bonds are illiquid and often do not trade frequently. Therefore recent trades prices are only a rough estimate of the current price that would be accepted. http://finra-markets.morningstar.com/BondCenter/Default.jsp